# Arraylist remove

Tags: java, arraylist

Need to do a method which takes  `ArrayList<ArrayList<<Integer>>`  and an `Integer` which then returns an `ArrayList<ArrayList<<Integer>>` from the orginal  `ArrayList<ArrayList<<Integer>>` which do not contain the `Integer` argument e.g

`ArrayList<ArrayList<<Integer>>`

`[[1,2,3],[7,5],[4,4,2],[8,12,3]]` and `Integer` `2` should return

`[[7,5],[8,12,3]]`. arraylist of arraylist integers.

not entirely sure how to access the inner loop

Comment: j < n.get(i).size()

Comment: Better if use for-each loop for this

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contains()` rather than worrying about writing an inner loop yourself.

Also, removing elements from lists while iterating is tricky. So, since you are not modifying the list and seem to be expected to return one, then just make a new list and add rather than remove.

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> removeTheNumber(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> n , Integer p){
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>();

  for(int i=0; i < n.size(); i++){
      ArrayList<Integer> innerList = n.get(i);
      if (!innerList.contains(p)) a.add(innerList);
    }

  return a;
}
```

Comment: And thanks for the edit. But I was already working on that myself ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice I appreciate it, how about if you needed to create a new arraylist whose internal ArrayList interger objects are copies of those from the orginal arraylist of arraylist integer objects

Comment: @helpmewithjava From what I understand, the list that is being returned here does contain copies of the lists from the original list.

Comment: Why not use an enhanced for loop? `for (ArrayList<Integer> innerList : n)`

Comment: Same concept. I was mostly pointing out the `contains` usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .contains of the inner lists to check as Integer class supports this. Below is a function and its test.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> removeTheNumber(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists, Integer n) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ArrayList<Integer> list: lists ) {
        if (!list.contains(n))
            result.add(list);
    }

    return result;
}

@Test
public void testRemoveNumber() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    lists.add(Lists.newArrayList(2,7,8));
    lists.add(Lists.newArrayList(6,7,9));
    lists.add(Lists.newArrayList(3,2,6));

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = removeTheNumber(lists, 2);

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(lists.get(1).toArray(new Integer[]{}), result.get(0).toArray(new Integer[]{}));
    result = removeTheNumber(lists, 7);
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(lists.get(2).toArray(new Integer[]{}), result.get(0).toArray(new Integer[]{}));
    result = removeTheNumber(lists, 6);
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(lists.get(0).toArray(new Integer[]{}), result.get(0).toArray(new Integer[]{}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend you have

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myArrayList = [[1,2,3],[7,5],[4,4,2],[8,12,3]];
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.length; i++) {
 //...
}
```

Your variable `i` is iterating through the initial `ArrayList`, which contains another `ArrayList`. So, `myArrayList[i]` will yield another `ArrayList`, which also has a length.
Building on this we have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.length; i++) {
  ArrayList<Integer> inner = myArrayList.get(i);
  for (int j = 0; j < inner.length; j++) {
    //now we may check for the existence of our integer
  }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering too. There are some folks who like to downvote on answers to "obvious duplicated" questions; but I dont see that here. Anyway, I will do what I can to fix that.

Comment: @cricket_007 Oops, meant `myArrayList[i]`. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Even that isn't valid. You'd use `.get(i)`

Comment: @cricket_007 You wouldn't be able to access the elements in the inner `ArrayList` using `(myArrayList[i])[j]`? I've never developed in Java before, but I'm fairly certain this is valid in the other languages I've used.

Comment: Java does not use square bracket notation for Collection objects, no. Those are only for arrays.

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah, I see. I'll update my answer then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use two loops you can write it like this (where array is your input array, and toSearch is your integer):

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayToReturn = new ArrayList<>();

    for(ArrayList<Integer> listInner : array){
        boolean found = false;
        for(Integer elem : listInner) {
            if (elem == toSearch)
                found=true;
        }
        if(found!=true)
            arrayToReturn.add(listInner);
    }

    arrayToReturn.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Of course i reccomend to use java 8, and then you can simply write it like this:

```
arrayToReturn = array.stream().filter(elem ->
!elem.contains(toSearch)).collect(
Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>::new));

        arrayToReturn.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: If you use `contains()` in the stream version, why not use it in the non-stream version?

Comment: For the first piece of code i wanted to use two loops, as it was asked in question